# Tax Price Round off issue Magento 2

Tags: magento2.3, price

I have placed one order in my Magento 2 store and it's working perfectly but in sales order the tax price round off issue in some order. When I have place order with multiple items the round off-price issue for this sees below snap.

https://prnt.sc/u6qjfi

And if I place only this 2 item order the price should be perfect in order, for this see below snap.

https://prnt.sc/u6qgzs

Any one have solution for this.

Answer (score 1):

As per the above issue, I have used the below module in the M2 site and the tax rounding issue sorted.

https://github.com/meanbee/magento2-tax-rounding

It's working for me.

Thanks